# Freelance work available

Tags: queries

I am looking for some support as the developer who built my site (www.lexiconthai.com) is no longer available.

I need a few small changes doing right now (adding meta tag plug in, changing fonts), but will need small jobs doing on a regular basis.

Any idea where I can find someone to support me?

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question, it's a job post.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the appropriate place for such a request. You can however register for the [Craft CMS Slack](http://craftcms.slack.com/) where there is a #jobs channel.